# <!--nextpage--> as a shortcode within the loop?

Tags: loop, shortcode, nextpage

Anyone implemented this successfully? I want to include the `<!--nextpage-->` within a single post loop as a shortcode. I tried to echo it, the tag shows up but the post doesn't get divided into pages.

I need to able to echo `do_shortcode('[nextpage]');` within the `single.php` and actually divide it into different pages...

Comment: The closest you are going to come here is using the approach by @birgire. I don't think what you are trying to do will work because you cannot split `the_content()` in such a way

Comment: have you find the method @DavidReis ? cause im looking for it too

Answer (score 2):

### Using the `the_posts` filter:

Here's one idea using the `the_posts` filter, that fires before `setup_postdata()` is activated:

```
/**
 * Replace [nextpage] with <!--nextpage--> through the 'the_posts' filter.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183980/26350
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts )
{
    $posts = array_map( function( $p )
    {
        if ( false !== strpos( $p->post_content, '[nextpage]' ) )
            $p->post_content = str_replace( '[nextpage]', '<!--nextpage-->', $p->post_content ); 
        return $p;
    }, $posts );
    return $posts;
});
```

The reason why your approach doesn't work, is that your `[nextpage]` shortcode is generated after the `setup_postdata()`, that handles the post pagination, has checked for `<!--nextpage-->` in the post content.

### Example:

Here I test it with some [WordPress Lorem Ipsum](https://spinpress.com/labs/wordpress-ipsum/):

[image: back-end]

with the following output on the front-end of the *TwentyFifteen* default theme:

[image: front-end]

Comment: Thanks @birgire should i copy that to my functions.php and then just do_shortcode [nextpage] on my single template?

Comment: didnt work for me...

Comment: try to add this code snippet into the `functions.php` or better yet as a plugin. This approach doesn't need you to define `[nextpage]` as a shortcode. So try to add `[nextpage]` in the post content and see what happens on the front-end.

Comment: @DavidReis did some testing, seems to work as expected

Comment: hmm still doesnt work.

Comment: I tested this on the TwentyTwelve, TwentyFourteen and TwentyFifteen default themes. @DavidReis

Comment: oh i see what you are saying but i need to use the shortcode within the single.php code (its a specific loop that i have in place) so i need to be able to do echo do_shortcode('[nextpage]'); and make the post divide into another page. thanks for the screenshots though!

Comment: ok no problem, I guess I'm just not fully understanding your setup & requirements. But best of luck with the project. @DavidReis