# wp_link_pages shortcode for 'nextpagelink'

Tags: shortcode, pagination, wp-link-pages

I want 'nextpagelink' shortcode **[nextpage_shortcode]** that I can place inside content.

I've seen threads where they say that you can't place anything related to the wp_link_pages inside content due to the way the content is rendered by Wordpress.

As you can see the text of 'nextpagelink' changes depending on the slide #.

I want the shortcode to reflect that.

Here is the schematic of what I am looking to do:

[image]

Both 'BEGIN' buttons link to the 2nd slide.

This is what I am currently working on:

```
function nextpage_shortcode( $atts ) { wp_link_pages( array(

'before' => '<div id="slideshow">',
'after' => '</div>',
'next_or_number' => 'next', 
'nextpagelink' => ( get_query_var('page') < 2 ) ? '<span id="next"> BEGIN </span>' : '<span id="next"> NEXT </span>' ) );

return ['nextpagelink'];
} add_shortcode( 'nextpage_short', 'nextpage_shortcode' );
```

Its works somewhat.

Its posts the 'nextpagelink' button above content, but not inside the content.

Not sure how to proceed.

Please help!

Comment: This has been answered at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183978/nextpage-as-a-shortcode-within-the-loop

Comment: Thanks for your response! Correct me I am wrong but the link you've provided simply turns <!--nextpage--> into a shortcode. I don't want [nextpage_shortcode] to actually split content. I want it to refer to the <!--nextpage--> below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_link_pages()` by default echoes the links (or the output), unless you set the `echo` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/#parameters) to `0` (or `false`). Secondly, your code is returning an `array` with `nextpagelink` as the only item/value.

But anyway, if you just want the link to the next page, the `wp_link_pages()` wouldn't be the one you should be using since it outputs all the page links (start, next, previous, etc.).

Instead, you can try this, which works well for me:

```
function nextpage_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $page, $numpages, $multipage;
    if ( $multipage ) {
        $i = max( 1, $page );
        if ( $i < 2 ) {
            $text = '<span id="next"> BEGIN </span>';
        } elseif ( $i < $numpages ) {
            $text = '<span id="next"> NEXT </span>';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $text ) ) {
            $link = _wp_link_page( $i + 1 );
            return $link . $text . '</a>';
        }
    }
    return '';
}
add_shortcode( 'nextpage_short', 'nextpage_shortcode' );
```

However, you should know that I'm using `_wp_link_page()` which is a private function. So you might want to [copy the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_link_page/#source), rename the function (e.g. to `my_link_page`), and use `my_link_page()` in the above code.

I hope that helps, and remember that the `<!--more-->` tag (i.e. content teaser) is not being taken into account since you're specifically dealing with the `<!--nextpage-->` tag only.

Comment: Btw, did you mean `add_shortcode( 'nextpage_shortcode', 'nextpage_shortcode' );` and not `add_shortcode( 'nextpage_short', 'nextpage_shortcode' );`? (note the *nextpage_short* vs *nextpage_shortcode*)

Comment: Thanks so much! Works Beautifully! I meant the latter. So that the actual shortcode would be [nextpage_short]

Comment: Ah, okay. :) And you're welcome. I'm glad I could help!